# Change icon of a folder via JSOM/REST

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, jsom, document-set

SP2013 on-premise: I sporadically happens that a document set gets created and is displayed with a folder icon rather than a document set icon.

Does anyone have a JSOM/REST snippet to change a document sets' icon (back to the original)?

Comment: Are you creating document set from UI or using code? Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288764/sharepoint-online-javascript-creates-folder-instead-of-document-set) similar question forum. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Ganesh thanks for the reply. We create the document set OOTB, no script involved. We have a custom content type though. Sometimes it creates doc sets with proper icon sometimes it doesn't.. changing CT to folder and back to doc set does not help. Even if we fix it we'd need to change the exsiting icons, would you have such?